# CSS Grid/Flex: two columns of the same width and one with auto width

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

How can I make two columns have the same width. Since the width is given in function of the column with greater width. And a third occupying the "width" remains.

Left, center and right column. I want the left column to have the same width as the right column. And this width is given by the width of the column with greater amount of text.

Example:
Column LEFT with text: ABCDEFGHIJK
This column has 150px
Column RIGHT with text: ABC
This column has 30px

I want this:

```
Column LEFT: 150px
Column CENTER: 100%
Column RIGHT: 150px
```

But I do not know the width. This is given by the column that has more text, then greater width.

If LEFT is greater than RIGHT, then width RIGHT is equal th width LEFT.
If LEFT is less than RIGHT, then width LEFT is equal the width RIGHT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if there is a direct way to achieve this using CSS, but one idea is to have the text duplicated in a column direction to be sure you have the same width then hide one of them.

I will use CSS variables for the text to avoid the duplication of the text in the html code:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 80px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.left,
.right {
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.middle {
  background: green;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.left:before {
  content: var(--tl);
}

.right:before {
  content: var(--tr);
}


/*hidden text*/

.left:after {
  content: var(--tr);
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0;
}

.right:after {
  content: var(--tl);
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" 
  style="--tr:'some text';
         --tl:'mooooore text here'">

  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="middle"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>

<div class="container" 
  style="--tr:'a looooong text here !!!';
         --tl:'a text'">

  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="middle"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I thought there was some solution with flex or grid. the other alternative would be with js, but this pleases me more.